# In ES6 with react, can I destructure an object just once for use in multiple methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, es6-class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default function(strategies = []) {
    class Authentication extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super()
            this.state = {
                allGreen: true
            }
        }
        componentWillMount() {
            const { history } = this.props
            strategies.map(strategy => {
                if (!this.props.auth[strategy]) {
                    this.setState({ allGreen: false })
                    history.replace('/')
                }
            })
        }
        componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
            const { history } = this.props
            strategies.map(strategy => {
                if (!nextProps.auth[strategy]) {
                    this.setState({ allGreen: false })
                    history.replace('/')
                }
            })
        }
        render() {
            if (!this.state.allGreen) return (<div></div>)

            return this.props.children
        }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            auth: state.auth
        }
    }

    return connect(mapStateToProps)(Authentication)
}
```

I'm using 'destructor object' usually in ES6

For example, const { history } = this.props like.

However, I want to know whether there is an efficient way to have just one object destruction, and use it in all of component's method.(componentWillMount, componentWillUpdate ...)

Above picture, I used object destruction twice in componentWillMount method and componentWillUpdate method. ( const { history } = this.props )

I want to destruct object just once! Is there any solution ?

Comment: May you post the example javascript as text rather than an image?

Comment: @evolutionxbox sure

Comment: You mean destructuring, not destruction, correct?

Comment: @Pekka웃 i don't know exact term, I mean the action like 
const { history } = this.props

Comment: Yeah, create a method `getHistory()`, and get it like that, then you only need to change it in 1 place in case this prop would change

Comment: Yeah, that's called destructuring. Destruction would mean to *destroy* the variable. Worth editing. :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thank you

Comment: It depends how this feature is implemented. If it is just syntactic sugar then  there is no performance gain from actually minimising the use of this in code!

Answer (score 4):

There's not performance issues on using destructurization multiple times (you are not expanding the whole object if this is your fear).

An ES 6 code like::

```
const aaa = {
  a: 5,
  b: 'ffff'
}

const { bbb } = aaa;
```

... is translated to...

```
var aaa = {
  a: 5,
  b: 'ffff'
};

var bbb = aaa.bbb;
```

Try it to https://babeljs.io

So use it, or simply use `this.props.history`

Comment: Ok Thank you. I just don't want to write same desturcturing twice.. seems like I have no option :)